# From a file count number of occurences with a grep stoping at a character

Tags: linux, perl

I need to count user accounts, user groups and missing info from /etc/passwd
and output it with a print

passwd file inside example:

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash

dnsmasq:x:106:65534:dnsmasq,,,:/var/lib/misc:/bin/false

libuuid:x:100:101::/var/lib/libuuid:
```

Separating in rows by ":" i need row 1,3 and 5

Been searching and cant find an aswer please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have already managed to read the passwd file line by line. Once you have a line loaded into a var (eg. `$line`) then you can use split.

```
my ($user, $gid, $info) = (split /:/, $line)[0, 3, 4];
```

Items are zero-indexed, so the first "column" is 0.

**EDIT**

I don't know how you're determining if user info is "missing" so I have left that out, but you can use the same techniques I have used for either accounts or groups depending on your need. When you count groups, you want to avoid counting duplicate groups. To do this I add the gid as a hash key. If we later encounter the same group, the key already exists and we are not increment anything. Later we just count the keys.

Also a correction... groupid is actually column 4 (split 3). Column 3 (split 2) is the userid, and there would be as many as those as there are accounts.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $content, '<', '/etc/passwd'
  or die "Could not open: $!";

my $accounts;
my %groups;

while( my $line = <$content>)  {   
    # Increment user count
    $accounts++;

    # Get group add it to hash to avoid duplicates
    my ($gid) = (split /:/, $line)[3];
    $groups{$gid} = 1;
}
close $content;

printf("Number of accounts: %d\n", $accounts);
printf("Number of groups: %d\n", scalar keys %groups);
```

Comment: That helps alot but the problem is still the count, the ouput should be something like `Number of Accounts: 22`, `Number of Groups: 12`, `Missing Info: 2`

Comment: You should post the code you have so far so people can see exactly how/where you're getting stuck.

Comment: Thank you soo much that solved my problem. From here should easier to figure out the missing info. Thanks